# Calling a function on select box onchange is calling multiple times

Tags: jquery, onchange

I am using bootpag plugin for pagination, but issue is not with that I think. Here is part of my script

```
$("#select-2").change(function() {            
   var selectedv = $("#select-2 option:selected").text();                               
   showresults(selectedv);  
});

function showresults(noofresults){
   getResults('http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize='+noofresults+'&page=0'); 

$('.demo4_top').bootpag({
        total: Math.ceil($("#resultscount").text()/noofresults),
        page: 1,
        maxVisible: 4       
}).on("page", function(event, num){
    alert(noofresults);
    getResults('http://192.168.1.122:10039/wps/mycontenthandler/vamshi/!ut/p/digest!SqaCnIAqyulFhaUStKGgJQ/searchfeed/search?query=*&scope=1440172377201&start=0&results=1000&pageSize='+noofresults+'&page=' + $.trim(num-1));

}).find('.pagination');

}
```

Actually my select box contains values 1,2,3. When I change values in select box they are staying in the variable, I mean you can see an alert in my showresults function, that alert is alerting multiple times. If I changes the value from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 1 and then call on page function of my bootpag plugin it is alerting all values 1,2,3,1.

What is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Replace your codes here

```
$("#select-2").change(function() {            
   var selectedv = $(this).val();                               
   showresults(selectedv);  
});
```

As per guess ,you are using "select 2 jquery" .so do as below-

```
$('#select-2').select2()
        .on("change", function(e) {
         showresults(e.val);  
        })
```

Comment: There is no diff between ur script n mine. Functionality doesn't change